# docker-compose remove services on exit (or recreate on start)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose file that runs 4 services:

- web
- db
- redis
- selenium

I would like the containers of services redis and selenium to always start fresh when I execute docker-compose, while preserving the state of web and db.

I don't mind if this is achieved destroyng the containers on exit or recreating new ones on start. At the moment I run this command:

```
docker-compose rm selenium && docker-compose rm redis && docker-compose up
```

I would prefer to have the same behavior using the docker-compose.yml file, instead of the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) **--force-recreate** flag when executing **up**, to always recreate containers and [configure volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) to persist databases data (on a local directory or a docker volume).